# VS 2015 crashing when editing razor views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I got this problem: while debugging ASP.NET MVC projects I should be able to update razor views with ease and refresh the browser to see the imediate results, but when I try to do this Visual Studio freezes a lot and I have to stop debugging and sometimes to close the editor via Task Manager.

Is there any solution to this, if yes, what can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue. Installing Visual Studio 2015 update rc1 worked for me. 
You can download it from:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx

Comment: The thing is that I have installed VS 2015 after the update was released, but I will give it a try anyway.

Comment: Update: I have updated VS, it seems to be smoother and it will let me edit razor views. Thanks for advice.